# Product attribute must be set, but is greyed out

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, configurable-product

[image: Error Message]

So I am getting this error message when I try to save a configurable product. I've made the field mandatory and entered sizes on all the simple products, but now Magento (2) wants me to put in a size for the configurable product even though I can't...

Is there a way to fix this? Or will I have to have the field as optional, rather than mandatory?

[image: Size Field]

This is the greyed out field it would like me to enter a size into.

Comment: how many variations in your product?

Comment: I have 4 variants of the product.